# Get name of the parsed file?

Tags: antlr

I would like to parse a file where the first line may or may not contain a definition of a "project" name (like with Pascal's `program` keyword), and if not, use the name of the file that is being parsed as default. Simplified:

```
@members{ String projectName; }

project :  {projectName = ...} // name of parsed file as default
         ( PROJECTNAMEKEYWORD ID {projectName = $ID.text;} )? 
           otherstuff {/*...*/};
```

Is this even possible? I found this surprisingly hard to find out using google or the antlr manual. By its documentation, `input.getSourceName()` should be what I am looking for, but it always returns null, and debugging lead me to the class `ANTLRStringStream` that has a `name` field whose value is returned by this method but never set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a custom constructor in your parser that takes a string that represents your file.

A demo:

```java
grammar T;

@parser::members {
  private String projectName;

  public TParser(String fileName) throws java.io.IOException {
    super(new CommonTokenStream(new TLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(fileName))));
    projectName = fileName;
  }

  public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
  }
}

parse
  :  (PROJECT ID {projectName = $ID.text;})? EOF
  ;

PROJECT : 'project';
ID      : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
SPACE   : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();};
```

which can be tested with:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // 'empty.txt' is, as the name suggests, an empty file
    TParser parser = new TParser("empty.txt");
    parser.parse();
    System.out.println(parser.getProjectName());

    // 'test.txt' contains a single line with the words: 'project JustATest'
    parser = new TParser("test.txt");
    parser.parse();
    System.out.println(parser.getProjectName());
  }
}
```

If you run the Main class, the following will be printed to your console:

```
empty.txt
JustATest
```